# mobile application keep loading when call to @OAuthSecurity resource

Tags: java, angular, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mfp

Good day,

I have a mobile application and call to mobileFirstPlatform and then only go to my backend service.

I am not sure my understanding is correct or not, in order to call to my Adapter Resource with `@OAuthSecurity`, I need to authenticate success with mfp first, then only able to access to that resource.

In my mobileFirst Console, I have configure this as my Scope-Elements Mapping and Mandatory Application Scope:
[image]

The following is part of my frontend code in `login.component.ts`:

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.mfpAuthenticationService.initEventHandler();
      this.initAuthHandle();
}

  initAuthHandle() {
    this.authSuccessEventSubscription = this.mfpAuthenticationService.authSuccessEvent.subscribe((loginResponse: any) => {
// do something after success login
});

this.authFailureEventSubscription = this.mfpAuthenticationService.authFailureEvent.subscribe((res: any) => {

      console.log('authFailureEvent => ', res);

      if (res.errorCode == WLErrorCodeConstant.ClientSideError.CHALLENGE_HANDLING_CANCELED && this.mfpAuthenticationService.isBiometricAuthenticated()) {

        return;

      } else {

        this.handleLoginError(res);

        this.loginForm.resetForm();

        this.processLogin = false;

      }

    });

    this.authChallengeEventSubscription = this.mfpAuthenticationService.authChallengeEvent.subscribe((res: any) => {

      console.log('authChallengeEvent => ', res);

      let redirectPath = this.sessionService.getSessionStorage(SessionName.REDIRECT_PATH);

      if (redirectPath) {

        console.log('biometric user login error => ', res);

        this.login.password = null;

        this.isLoginButtonClicked = false;

        this.baseService.handleError(res, true);

      } else {

        this.handleLoginError(res);

      }

      this.loginForm.resetForm();

      this.processLogin = false;

    });
}

performLogin() {
this.mfpAuthenticationService.performLogin(this.login.username, this.loginRequest);
}
```

And this is some code on `mfp.auth.service.ts`:

```
initEventHandler() {
        console.log("come mfp.auth.service.ts initEventhandler");
        this.currentEventHandler = '';
        this.userLoginChallengeHandler = null;
        this.userLoginChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createSecurityCheckChallengeHandler('UserAuthentication');
        this.userLoginChallengeHandler.securityCheckName = '';
        this.userLoginChallengeHandler.handleSuccess = (loginSuccess) => {
            console.log("handleSuccess");
            this.isChallenged = false;
            if (this.currentEventHandler != this.eventHandler.success) {
                this.currentLoginGrantType = this.processLoginGrantType;
                //alert("initEventHandler|loginSuccess=\n" + JSON.stringify(loginSuccess));
                console.log("loginSuccess is " + JSON.stringify(loginSuccess));
                this.mfpAuthResponse = {
                    id: loginSuccess.id,
                    accessToken: loginSuccess.user.attributes.access_token,
                    tokenType: loginSuccess.user.attributes.token_type,
                    expiresIn: loginSuccess.user.attributes.expires_in,
                    scope: loginSuccess.user.attributes.scope,
                    clientId: loginSuccess.user.attributes.client_id
                };
            }
            this.currentEventHandler = this.eventHandler.success;
            console.log("handler success, challenged is " + this.isChallenged);
        };

        this.userLoginChallengeHandler.handleFailure = (loginError) => {
            console.log("handleFailure");
            this.isChallenged = false;
            if (this.currentEventHandler != this.eventHandler.failure) {
                this.authFailureEvent.emit(loginError);
            }
            this.currentEventHandler = this.eventHandler.failure;
            console.log("handleFailure, challenged is " + this.isChallenged);
        };

        this.userLoginChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = (challenge) => {
            console.log("handleChallenge " + challenge);
            this.isChallenged = true;
            this.challengeResponseModel = challenge;
            this.authChallengeEvent.emit(challenge);
            this.currentEventHandler = this.eventHandler.challenge;
            console.log("handleChallenge, challenged is " + this.isChallenged);
        };
    }

performLogin(username: string, loginRequest: RequestModel<LoginRequestModel>) {
        console.log("come mfp.auth.service.ts performLogin");
        let performed = false;
        let authRequest = {
            requestHeader: {
                deviceId: this.sessionService.getDeviceId(),
                channelTime: new Date().toString()
            },
            requestBody: loginRequest.requestBody
        }
        this.processLoginGrantType = loginRequest.requestBody.grant_type;

        let authObj = {
            'authorization': environment.authorization,
            'authRequest': JSON.stringify(authRequest),
            'authCode': this.service.getHashMAC(authRequest, this.sessionService.getHashKey()),
            'authUser': username
        };
        console.log("mfp-performLogin|isChallenged1=" + this.isChallenged + "\nauthObj=\n" + JSON.stringify(authObj) + "\n\n");
        if (this.isChallenged) {
            console.log("mfp-performLogin|submitChallengeAnswer=");
            this.userLoginChallengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer(authObj);
        } else {
            console.log("mfp-performLogin|WLAuthorizationManager.login=");
            WLAuthorizationManager.login(this.securityCheckName, authObj).then(
                () => {
                    console.log("mfp-performLogin|WLAuthorizationManager.login.performed=" + performed + "\nmfpAuthResponse=\n" + JSON.stringify(this.mfpAuthResponse) + "\n\n");
                    if (!performed) {
                        this.ngZone.run(() => {
                            console.log("come emit authSuccessEvent");
                            this.authSuccessEvent.emit(this.mfpAuthResponse);
                        });
                    }
                    performed = true;
                },
                (err) => {
                    console.log("mfp-performLogin|WLAuthorizationManager.login.err=\n\n" + JSON.stringify(err) + "\n");
                    console.log('wllogin err => ', err);
                    this.authFailureEvent.emit(err);
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

As you can see, from my `login.component.ts`, i will do `ngOnInit()` first, and after I key in password and press on login button, it will call the `performLogin()` method, and continue to call to `mfp.auth.servicet.ts performLogin()`.

In `mfp.auth.servicet.ts performLogin()`, will call to `WLAuthorizationManager.login(this.securityCheckName, authObj)` because the `this.isChallenged` value is false by default.

The login is actually successful, as I able to get those `oauth` response and able to go into my application, my `oauth` response is something as follow:

[image]

The login is successful, but when I want to click to access to resource that having `@OAuthSecurity`, then my app will keep loading, and no error show in log. Something is blocking in mfp there.

If I remove the Scope-Element Mapping, and Mandatory Application Scope, then no issue, the request can go in successful.

Thus, I am suspecting something wrong in my configuration, or something wrong in my code logic. Really appreciate your advise and help. I am stuck in this more than 2 weeks.

As my understanding, there are 2 part of authentication on this, 1 is authentication with mfp, and another 1 is authentication with my backend service, which is the `UserAuthentication.java`, I believe my `UserAuthentication.java` already success authenticated, maybe something wrong with my authentication part with mfp?

And how can I know I have successful authenticate with mfp ya?

Base on this article, http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/credentials-validation/javascript/
And may I know when the `handleChallenge()` will be call? and also the `handleSuccess()`.

Kindly let me know if need me to provide more information.

Comment: The token object in the query is a custom one, yes? Is this from the backend? If so, is this token sent along with the protected resource call as an Authorization header?

Comment: hi @VivinK, do u means accessToken: loginSuccess.user.attributes.access_token, ? Yes its from my backend, the value will be something like 767eb9ff-09f2-4559-81c0-5f6e642c16fc

Comment: handleChallenge() will be call? and also the
?

--> handleChallenge() will be called when you are trying to access resource protected with UserAuthentication security check and success state for UserAuthentication security check has expired. You must answer the challenge to proceed further. 

 handleSuccess() -- > success state for UserAuthentication security check is valid. 

handleFailure() --> If you exceeds the number of attempt to answer the challenge for ex: you submit wrong credentials more than number of attempt set in the adapter

Comment: And also I see you have added UserAuthentication as mandatory scope which means for every call you make to server you will be validated first on success state expiration of UserAuthentication security check, if valid --> allow to access resource else throw challenge ( handleChalleneg())